# Copying the matched row in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have two Sheets, sheet1 and sheet 2. 
I am looking into column T of sheet1 and pasting the complete row if T contains 1 in sheet 2. 
The code, works good, but it paste the result in sheet2 in the same row in sheet1.
This results in blanks, between the rows. Can anyone suggest, what i should Change with my code, so that i get them in sequence without any blank rows.
Also, how can I copy the Header in row 1 from sheet 1 to sheet2?

```
Sub Test()
For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("T:T")
    If Cell.Value = "1" Then
        matchRow = Cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets(2).Select
        ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets(1).Select
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s

Comment: Re-opened the question as OP doesn't want to use Autofilter. He wants to loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use `Select` and `Selection` to copy paste, it will only slows down your code's run-time.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim Cell As Range
Dim NextRow as Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("T1:T" & Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row)
    If Cell.Value = "1" Then
        NextRow = Sheets(2).Cells(Sheets(2).Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row
        Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Range("A" & NextRow + 1)
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry i will have to close this quesiton as a duplicate:D

Comment: Why is that so ?

Comment: @SiddharthRout that's not nice ;)

Comment: BTW looping through entire `Range("T:T")` would be really painful. Autofilter would be much faster?

Comment: @SiddharthRout i've modifed to loop through occupied range. I think it's fast enough, anyway, I don't think confusing VBA beginers with `AutoFilter` is that good

Comment: The problem with your code is that sheet2 will have lot of blanks because of `Sheets(2).Range("A" & Cell.Row)`

Comment: If you want to loop then I can edit your code if you want?

Comment: @ShaiRado Its not working.No row has been pasted in sheet 2.

Comment: @ShaiRado the edited code, is still copying the rows in sheet2 as same Location as sheet 1, I want it in one the other without blank

Comment: @SiddharthRout I want it to loop

Comment: If Shai wants I can edit his post. I have the code ready @Mikz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147687/discussion-between-mikz-and-siddharth-rout).

Answer (score 2):

**Not For Points**

Apologies, but I couldn't stop myself from posting an answer. It pains me when I see someone wanting to use an inferior way of doing something :(

I am not in favor of looping. It is very slow as compared to [Autofilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s).

If you **STILL** want to use looping then you can make it faster by not copying the rows in the loop but in the end in **ONE GO**...

Also if you do not like living dangerously then always fully qualify your object else you may end up copying the wrong row.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, r As Long
    Dim copyRng As Range

    Set wsI = Sheet1: Set wsO = Sheet2

    wsO.Cells.Clear

    '~~> first available row in sheet2
    r = 2

    With wsI
        lRow = .Range("T" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Copy Headers
        .Rows(1).Copy wsO.Rows(1)

        For i = 1 To lRow
            If .Range("T" & i).Value = 1 Then
                If copyRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set copyRng = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set copyRng = Union(copyRng, .Rows(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    If Not copyRng Is Nothing Then copyRng.Copy wsO.Rows(r)
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**
[image]